# dynamic programming coin change that return an array

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I am trying to get all the coins that are the sum of target amount. I was able to get the amount of coins needed. How would i go about solving it.

You can use the same coins unlimited 
eg. `change([2], 10)` => `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]`

```
def change(coins, amount):
    result = [amount+1] * (amount+1)

    result[0] = 0

    for i in range(1, amount+1):
        for coin in coins:
            if i >= coin:
                result[i] = min(result[i], result[i-coin] + 1)

    if result[amount] == amount+1:
        return -1

    return result[amount]
```

`change([1, 2, 5,8], 7)` => `[5, 2]` order does not matter.

Comment: Please explain, in further detail, what you want to happen.

Comment: do you want all the result or the best result from dynamic programming? if you want all result, dynamic programming does not work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use [`dyanmic programming`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) you can only get the best result, you can achieve this by using a array to store the middle result of `dynamic programming`, I have modified based on your dp version:

```
def change(coins, amount):
    result = [amount+1] * (amount+1)
    coins_results = [[] for _ in range(amount+1)]

    result[0] = 0

    for i in range(1, amount+1):
        for coin in coins:
            if i >= coin and result[i - coin] + 1 < result[i]:
                result[i] = result[i-coin] + 1
                coins_results[i] = coins_results[i-coin] + [coin]

    if result[amount] == amount+1:
        return []

    return coins_results[amount]
```

test:

```
print(change([1, 2, 5, 8], 7))
print(change([2], 10))
```

output:

```
[5, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

---

here is a version to output all the result by [`backtracking`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking):

```
def change(coins, amount):
    res = []

    def backtrack(end, remain, cur_result):
        if end < 0: return
        if remain == 0:
            res.append(cur_result)
            return
        if remain >= coins[end]:
            backtrack(end, remain - coins[end], cur_result + [coins[end]])
        backtrack(end - 1, remain, cur_result)

    backtrack(len(coins) - 1, amount, [])
    return res
```

test:

```
print(change([1, 2, 5, 8], 7))
print(change([2], 10))
```

output:

```
[[5, 2], [5, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: Thank you for you help, Its almost correct. when i used this testcase.
print(change([51, 1], 10))  it returns [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] instead.

Comment: if you want all the result, I can write a different version, but dynamic programming can only get the best result @Don

Comment: im trying to solve that problems on LeetCode here is the link
https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/
but i want to get it to return in a list. Id really appreciated your help. youre solid.

Comment: I think your code is the solution to this problem, if you want to get the specific result, you should edit your question here, because your desciption is `get all the coins that are the sum of target amount`, it is ambiguous : ) @Don

Comment: I have updated the version to output all the result, in case you needed. @Don

Comment: Yeah my description was wrong . Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to obtain all combinations that correspond to the target amount you can use the following generator:

```
def change(coins, amount):
    for i, coin in enumerate(coins):
        if coin == amount:
            yield (coin,)
        elif coin < amount:
            yield from ((coin,) + x for x in change(coins[i:], amount - coin))

print(list(change([2], 10)))  # [(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)]
print(list(change([1, 2, 5, 8], 7)))  # [(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 2, 2), (2, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the answer you are looking for, please develop your question so we can get a better understanding of what is needed to be done :)

```
def change(coins, amount):
    ret = []    # Here we keep all possible solves
    solves = [] # Here we keep all unique solves, to avoid duplicates (Eg.: [5, 2] and [2, 5] are both a solution to 7)

    for c1 in coins:
        for c2 in coins:
            if c1 + c2 == amount: # Check if the solve is a match
                solve = [c1, c2] 
                if not set(solve) in solves: # Check if the solve is not a duplicate
                    ret.append(solve)
                    solves.append(set(solve))

    return ret # Return a list of solves
```

Comment: May help if you expand your answer with info how you understood OP