# How to find the subset of n-element lists that sums up to a target n-element list?

Tags: algorithm, list, math, sum, time-complexity

**Given a list of n-element lists, A, and a target n-element list, t, find a set of lists, S, in A, whose lists sum up to t.**

Summing up lists, here, is the addition of elements at the same position. For example, the sum of [1 2] + [2 3] + [7 5] is [10 10].

---

**Here is an example of the problem:**

n = 4

A = [[1 2 3 4] [0 0 1 0] [1 0 0 1] [2 0 0 0] [3 0 0 2] [3 0 0 1] [0 0 0 1]]

t = [4 0 1 3]

*Then, we must find S.*

S = [[3 0 0 1] [0 0 0 1] [0 0 1 0] [1 0 0 1]]

---

Notice that we don't need all the sets of lists that add up to t -- we only need one.

---

This problem may seem similar to the [dynamic programming coin change that return an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55661242/dynamic-programming-coin-change-that-return-an-array).

Obviously, this problem can be done in brute force with time complexity of O(2^n) by going over the power set of A. *Is there a more optimal solution? Is there another problem similar to this?*

Comment: Im certain there is.  BUT we dont do your homework for you.  You should sit down and take a good wack at it.  Then post your attempt and we can tweak it! :)

Comment: @Fallenreaper Thank you for your reply. This is not a homework problem; it's a problem I encountered while working on a side project: https://github.com/Mandawi/ToWear. I'm not sure how to do it in another way. My current non-working solution is in the function findMin, here: https://github.com/Mandawi/ToWear/blob/master/points_to_english.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving your problem is equivalent to solving [Subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is NP-complete, so your problem is NP-complete too. It means that your problem can't be solved in polynomial time.

Although, if absolute values of all numbers in your lists are less than M, there is a [subset sum problem solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) in O(n*M*size(a)) (you just need to modify it to your problem, but it is still exponential relatively to number of bits in numbers and takes a lot of memory, but may be better than brute force in certain cases).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I forgot about the subset sum problem but I see the similarity. All numbers in my lists are between 0 and 10, N is 4, and the cardinality of A has a limit of 50 for my particular problem. I don't understand how the Pseudo-polynomial time dynamic programming solution for the subset sum relates to this, given I don't have any negative elements.

Comment: If you don't have negative values, then you count the sum of negative values as zero.

Comment: I think the wikipedia page you linked references Pisinger's solution. The solution is in O(n) per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962568/fast-solution-to-subset-sum-algorithm-by-pisinger. I will try to modify that solution to my problem. Thank you for the help!